# how to align 3 div horizontally and one div bottom of the middle div

Tags: html, css

How to align 4 divs like the following image using css

[image]

I used this code

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100px;background: #D78889;margin: 2px"></div> 
                <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100px;background: #D78AA9;margin: 2px"></div> 
                <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100px;background: #3D2B11;margin: 2px"></div> 
            </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" ></div> 
                <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100px;background: #D78AA9;margin: 2px"></div> 
                <div class="col-md-4" ></div> 
            </div>
```

But I think this is not a good idea

Comment: What have you already tried? What is your current code? Please provide more information.

Comment: Please take the time to read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  This is your third downvoted question and if you continue to ask poor quality and downvoted questions, you will get a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: If you want to use the Bootstrap framework, look into `offset`

Comment: you can also use the class`m-auto` flex children will then center on both axis and middle if single in the container ...

Comment: Could you please explain with the code. Actually, I don't know about that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100px;background: #D78889;margin: 2px">Left</div> 
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100px;background: #D78AA9;margin: 2px">Center</div> 
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100px;background: #3D2B11;margin: 2px">Right</div> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4" style="height: 100px;background: #D78AA9;margin: 2px">aligned underneath the centered div above me!</div>
</div>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: this is not working, the last div aligned underneath of the left div

Comment: can you provide a screenshot ? The screen width may differ here, we're using `col-md-*` classes maybe you should provide relevant `col-sm-*` classes for each `div`

Comment: for example, upload it to Google Drive or whatever and give the link.

Answer (score -1):

This should be useful.

```css
.row {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 bg-primary"></div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 bg-danger"></div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 bg-success"></div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 bg-warning offset-md-4"></div>
</div>
```